# Print class stack in python

Tags: python

I have the following three classes:

```
class foo(object):
    pass
class bar(foo):
    pass
class baz(bar):
    pass
```

I want a method that does something like this:

```
>>> class_stack(baz)
baz > bar > foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [MRO (method resolution order)](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/):

```
In [32]: baz.mro()
Out[32]: [__main__.baz, __main__.bar, __main__.foo, object]

In [33]: [cls.__name__ for cls in baz.mro()]
Out[33]: ['baz', 'bar', 'foo', 'object']

In [34]: ' > '.join([cls.__name__ for cls in baz.mro()])
Out[34]: 'baz > bar > foo > object'
```